# Failing to install Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 and having some issues.

I am installing from a USB and the install runs fine with nomodeset selected. Once installed the drive is not able to be selected in BIOS to boot from. I'm not really sure whats going on here but I read through some similar questions and they mention that grub may not be installed. I have tried to install it using the commands but I am not getting the drive to show up.

I tried the commands presented in [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1633758) and the drive is still not visible to boot.

Is there a method I should be using instead of install from USB?

I have also tried booting into **Try Ubuntu without installing** mode and reinstalling ubuntu on the drive. This still does not boot.

Edited with lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1    15G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1    15G  0 part /cdrom
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    1 117.4G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    1     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    1  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    1 101.5G  0 part /media/ubuntu/cc88650d-919d-4647-9259-3c9e15282
```

What is the best way to debug this problem?

i'm on UEFI and not trying to dual boot

Comment: UEFI or Legacy? Dual boot or standalone?

Comment: UEFI, Standalone I guess... I have windows installed on another drive but i have tried with it disconnected.

Comment: @DanielTate can you confirm that you have an `EFI` partition at the beginning of the disk?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh How do I confirm this

Comment: @DanielTate fairly easy, `lsblk` paste this in the terminal and update your question with resulting output, (note: you can do this in **try ubuntu without installing** mode even when your OS isn't working)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Does this help?

Comment: I don't see an EFI partition, you can create an EFI partition from within the Ubuntu installer, it should be 200mb (more or less) and recommendation is to keep it at the start of the disk https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I will try this now after reading the documentation. I will update with a @ tag if needed.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I'm not sure based on the documentation how to do this... I partitioned 200mb of space to the start of the disk at fat 32 at /boot and this did not help the problem.

Comment: Does 16.04 have these issues is it worth me trying that instead?

Comment: @DanielTate you don't need to do that, if you look at the bottom of all the partition choices you should see `EFI partition` as an option, if you're doing this through UEFI ofcource

Comment: I don't see that option.